# How could you kill a giant winged turtle like monster with medieval tech?

Tags: mythical-creatures

How could you kill a giant winged turtle-like monster with medieval tech?

This turtle has an about five foot thick shell and giant bat wings with which it can fly on but does not much, because it takes so much energy. It also has a huge scorpion tail and the monster can retract its entire body into its shell. It also has gills and can swim.

Comment: You'd leave it alone to die by being crushed underneath its own weight or die of starvation because it cannot move.

Comment: It sounds like a monster that would be quickly slain by the [square-cubed law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law).  To even exist, much less eat or breathe, this creature would depend entirely on magic.  As with all magic based opponents, their weaknesses are really for you to decide.

Comment: You're probably going to need to add some more specific information about your monster in order to get any good answers.

Comment: @Foxy, I see you used some **commas** this time, which is a good improvement!  However, you need to understand (and use) **periods** and capital letters.  Be sure to thank a4android for fixing your basic writing for you.

Comment: I honestly don't get why it got put on hold. The question is pretty straightforward, "how could you kill a giant, winged, turtle-like monster with medieval technology".

Comment: You tagged this question with [tag:mythical-creatures]. Do you have a specific mythical creature in mind? I am not aware of a myth involving such a turtle. If you were thinking about an existing myth it might be a good idea to give a short summary of what the myth is about and maybe link to a source for people who are interested in further information that is not needed to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classically we kill giant turtles by turning them upside down so that their legs can't reach the ground.  This can be accomplished with a concealed pit under the legs on one side to get the big boy off-skew, then have a bunch of knights with pole-arms ride in and push it over.

Your creature's wings and tail complicate this, but a medieval army can charge in and stand on those wings while a few dozen men grab the tail.

Once you have it upside down and pinned, you can just wait for the sun to cook the poor creature in its shell.

Answer (score 0):

Siege weaponry would be as useless as artillery fire in kaiju films. The only thing I can imagine in this highly implausible scenario, is to either lure it underground and cause a cave-in or have a garrison climb onto its back and hope it stings itself to death. Poisoning the creature with tainted offerings is possible, but boring.

Answer (score 0):

Just burn it.

Get a squad of light cavalry and pour oil in the creature when your other troops use hooks to slow down the creature.

Once your beast dies enjoy your reptilian barbeque

Comment: [Bur](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bur) it?  Sounds unpleasant .

Answer (score -1):

Where there’s giant turtles, you [also find giant elephants that like to stand on them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Turtle).  Spread [pheromones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pheromone) on the shell to attract more elephants than the normal 4, and/or induce this behavior before the individual is mature and can’t handle the load.

The [excessive weight will smother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asphyxia#Compressive_asphyxia) a juvenile, and hinder adults so it can’t feed and groom normally.  Either way, it’s a “natural” method that doesn’t have any toxic chemicals or overt weaponary.

Synthesizing a pheromone mimic from fermented [seaweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seaweed) would be preferable, and doable using medieval tech — that’s [just like making beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermentation#History_of_human_use).  Otherwise, you need to extract it from the [anal glands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_gland) of the turtle itself, which is hazardous and if you’re [in that position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_canal) you could just use a [poisoned spear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewer).